# Cloud build is failing with contentPlacementError

Tags: build, azure-pipelines

ERROR CAS Place(5BCD5261368E227DC9A9110B061749D81E87EDF184EA1A9507A894864A6B9C1C00,D:\IE\sources\Dev\src\API\objd\amd64\csx\roles\Tests.API.WebRole\base\x64\mswasri.dll,Writable,ReplaceExistingFile,CopyNoVerify) ContentPlacementError in 13ms

ERROR Cache GetContent(5BCD5261368E227DC9A9110B061749D81E87EDF184EA1A9507A894864A6B9C1C00,D:\IE\sources\Dev\src\Ingestion\API\objd\amd64\csx\roles\Tests.API.WebRole\base\x64\mswasri.dll,Writable,ReplaceExistingFile,CopyNoVerify) ContentPlacementError, Unknown size=0 wasLocal=False wasPinned=False in 19ms

Build clean and queued again. It was picking everything from cache and giving old version of files.

Comment: I think it's not really clear which build system you are using. If you add the according build platform tag you will likely get better response. Currently you are actively hiding your question from experts for your specific platform by using a non-specific meta-tag.

Comment: It was coming from CloudBuild (provided by Microsoft). This issue was coming intermittently and not reproducible anymore. It was coming only at a particular time period and after which it vanished without doing anything.